# JavaScript - Loop through required arguments list for a function

Tags: javascript, function

This is a bit of a weird situation, but say I have the following function:

```
function myFunction(name, age, job){...}
```

Is there a way to get keys / loop through the required params for it (not the argument array passed to it), so it would be something like:

```
for(required_param_keys_by_myFunction){
 console.log(key) // --> name, age, job
}
```

Comment: https://davidwalsh.name/javascript-arguments

Comment: I saw that question but was hoping for a better way, I mean these must be defined somewhere?

Comment: Hence I did not hammer close your question...

Comment: Please describe what the real goal is? Why would you want to print the names of those variables? Surely the code should work exactly the same if only the names of variables were changed. You are trying to do otherwise.

Comment: there is no new news.

Comment: Actually I'm trying to use that list to dynamically validate functions.